# Add items to Array in Dictionary

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I have a dictionary and want to add new strings to the items. My idea is to create a list of strings as `item` for each `key`.

My code is so far:

```
Sub AccountEntitlements()

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim acc As Worksheet
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim d As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim count As Long

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set acc = Sheets("accountsentitlements")
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    arr = sh1.Range("D:F")

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If d.Exists(arr(i, 3)) Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1) '<- Error line
            d(arr(i, 3)) = Array(arr(i, 1))
        Else
            d.Add Key:=arr(i, 3), Item:=Array(arr(i, 1))
        End If

    Next i

    For count = 1 To d.count - 1
        acc.Cells(count + 1, "D").Value = UCase(d.Keys()(count))
        acc.Cells(count + 1, "E").Value = d.Items()(count)
    Next count

End Sub
```

The **error message** is `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range`.

The important code block is

```
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
     If d.Exists(arr(i, 3)) Then
          ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1) '<- Error line
          d(arr(i, 3)) = Array(arr(i, 1))
     Else
          d.Add Key:=arr(i, 3), Item:=Array(arr(i, 1))
     End If
```

The key of a dictionary is the user account and the items should be their membership groups. 
Example:

> Key= ABCD , Item= Entitlement1, Entitlement2, etc.

**How can the item array be extended and include previous entries?**

Comment: Use a Dictionary or Collection instead of an array to hold the membership groups. And why create such a large array to loop through in the first place?

Comment: The error is because you can only `Redim Preserve` the last element of a multidimensional array.  Since you already  `arr= Range("D:F"), and your `Redim Preserve arr(...` statement must fail.  It is NOT acting on the array in the Dictionary.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, what do you mean with 'such a large array'? How would you split the array?

Comment: `arr = Range("D:F")` creates an array of dimensions `(1 to 1048576, 1 to 4)`.  Do you have that many items in your database?  For a good discussion, see the late Chip Pearsons article on [Arrays and Ranges in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I have 81.000 rows. Thank you for the link. I will check it out.

Comment: OK, so why do you need an array twelve times as large? It'll take a lot longer to loop through.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, Thank you so much for your comments. I have now joined the strings simply together in my dictionary and I have set the length of the array fitting to my data. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your assistance (@Ron Rosenfeld)!

Below is my final code part.

```
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If d.Exists(arr(i, 3)) Then
        d(arr(i, 3)) = d.Item(arr(i, 3)) & "," & arr(i, 1)
    Else
        d.Add Key:=arr(i, 3), Item:=arr(i, 1)
    End If
Next i
```

I was still testing whether I should concatenate the strings with `& "," &` or with the `JOIN()` function but decided eventually for the first option.

Regarding my array size, I added a row counter to fit the length of the array. `lrow = sh1.Cells(Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Row`.

Answer (score 1):

Among other problems:

You can only `ReDim` the last element of a multi-dimensional array.

Your line

```
arr = sh1.Range("D:F")
```

will create a 1-based 2D array: `arr(1 to 1048576, 1 to 4)`.  If you have a database with over `4*10^6` elements, you might want to consider a different tool.

So a valid command might be

```
Redim Preserve arr(1 to ubound(arr,1), 1 to ubound(arr,2)+1)
```

But that's not what your doing.  To accomplish what you want to do, try something like this:

```
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If d.Exists(arr(i, 3)) Then
        X = d(arr(i, 3))
        ReDim Preserve X(UBound(X, 1) + 1)
        X(UBound(X, 1)) = arr(i, 1)
        d(arr(i, 3)) = X
    Else
        d.Add Key:=arr(i, 3), Item:=Array(arr(i, 1))
    End If    
Next i
```

But why not just use a `Dictionary` or `Collection` to hold your list of items.  Then you don't have to worry at all about resizing your array.